# trace route vs ping time differences

Tags: networking, ping

when I am pinging an IP address the average time is 71.1 ms

When using tracert to the same ip shows much higher times (around 70 ms each node..), can you explain the differences?

```
C:\Users\user648026>ping 152.36.54.101

Pinging 152.36.54.101 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 152.36.54.101: bytes=32 time=89ms TTL=60
Reply from 152.36.54.101: bytes=32 time=64ms TTL=60
Reply from 152.36.54.101: bytes=32 time=71ms TTL=60
Reply from 152.36.54.101: bytes=32 time=63ms TTL=60

C:\Users\user648026>tracert 152.36.54.101

Tracing route to HOST-123 [152.36.54.101]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    69 ms    65 ms    70 ms  someIpWasHere
  2    94 ms    71 ms    65 ms  someIpWasHere
  3   148 ms    73 ms    64 ms  someIpWasHere
  4    72 ms    66 ms    66 ms  someIpWasHere
  5    64 ms    73 ms    65 ms  my host [152.36.54.101]

Trace complete.

C:\Users\user648026>tracert 152.36.54.101

Tracing route to HOST-123[152.36.54.101]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    70 ms    78 ms    63 ms  someIpWasHere
  2    68 ms   104 ms   101 ms  someIpWasHere
  3    69 ms   117 ms    65 ms  someIpWasHere
  4    72 ms    69 ms    71 ms  someIpWasHere
  5    65 ms    64 ms    65 ms  my host  [152.36.54.101]
```

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding this. I really don't see much difference. The traceroute in the second instance shows an average to the destination (`(65+64+65)/3=64.67)`) is actually lower than your ping average.

Comment: thanks, so what do the 3 columns represent?  ->    70 ms    78 ms    63 ms

Comment: The three columns represent the times for the three attempts. The last line represents the three times from the source to the destination (the entire path).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the output from traceroute. Each line represents a hop, and there are three attempts to each hop (the three columns). The intermediate hops can have fairly high times because something like generating an ICMP error messages is a fairly low priority for a router, and it will get to it when it has time, but its priority is actually routing packets.

The last line in what you have is the entire path from the source to the destination, and the three times for it are comparable to your ping times.